# Nested Accordion Menu issue with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to display the links `Test 1` & `Test 2` when I click on `Dropdown 1`. Currrently they disappear super fast. How can I fix this?

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/4dm318nn/

Here is my Javascript:

```
  $(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.inline').find('.navtoggle').click(function(){

      //Expand or collapse this panel
      $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

      //Hide the other panels
      $(".sub-menu").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

    });
  });
```

Comment: Do you want them visible?

Comment: That's right. When `Dropdown 1` is clicked, I want to make them completely visible rather than disappear.

Comment: You just have to be a bit more specific I think. Try something like `$(this).next('.submenu').not(...)...` to target the specific one rather than all submenus in general.

Comment: My apologies. I'll be more specific with my next question :-)
I'd just like to open all nested submenus when I click 'Dropdown 1'. Is this possible?

Comment: This dirty hack resolves my issue a little, but it's not perfect:
http://jsfiddle.net/4dm318nn/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This dirty hack resolves my issue a little, but it's not perfect: jsfiddle.net/4dm318nn/1

```
<nav class="medium-8 columns primary menu">
    <ul class="inline naked">
        <li class="primary-item"><a href="http://localhost:8888/test/wordpress">Home</a></li>                       
        <li id="menu-item-74" class="primary-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-74"><a href="#" class="navtoggle">Dropdown 1</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-76" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-76"><a href="http://localhost:8888/test/wordpress/?page_id=45">Dropdown 2</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-77" class="sub-sub-menu menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-77"><a href="http://localhost:8888/test/wordpress/?page_id=47">Test 1</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-78" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-78"><a href="http://localhost:8888/test/wordpress/?page_id=49">Test 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

  $(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.inline').find('.navtoggle').click(function(){

      //Expand or collapse this panel
      $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

      //Hide the other panels
      $(".sub-menu").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

    });
  });
```